AWS Glue Job Argument error: option --key_name(argument) not recognized while running a glue job triggered by Lambda which passes the arguments to Job
I am running a glue job with python script shell(version 3.9) and glue version is 3.0. I am passing 8 arguments to the glue job and accessing it using getResolvedOptions(args, options). One of the argument is not recognized and checked the logs it is saying error: option --key_name(argument) not recognized . May I know the reason for this error?
I have tried reducing the arguments to 5 then it is working fine.
Image of the error in cloudwatch logs
